# Unable to make Custom Time Spinner

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker

I want to create a time spinner which has minutes with 15 minutes interval as 0, 15, 30, 45. I've searched a lot and found few codes but just one worked out but it has intervals of 1, however on scrolling the value does change with the interval of 15 but wheel shows only increment or decrements of 1.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxdKi.jpg)

these links are the screenshots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBIED.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

yo ucan create custom view or just simple layout file and use inside NumberPicker which has method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html#setDisplayedValues(java.lang.String[]) where you can set displayed values, eg: hours from range 00-23 (just set min value for picker and max Value) : and the minutes picker with the mothod from link,
hope i helped

Comment: yes it was helpful, but actually we have already used timepicker and need to implement the changes using timepicker only, otherwise we shall have to make a lot of changes in our code, so is there any way to do that usin time picker instead of number picker?

Comment: unfortunately i think the easiest way will be creating custom view that implements exact same methods you used from timepicker and change the reference to it so for example:
`public class CustomTimePicker extends View {

// implement constructors (3 basic)

public Integer getCurrentHour()
{
// implement returning from hour number picker
}

// etc
}`

here you have very good tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html , sorry for the poorlyformatted code i'm new here;)

Comment: if you will keep the same outer interface and name of the component it will come to changing the imports;)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out :)